# column count doesn't match value

Tags: php

```
$a = mysqli_query(
    $koneksi, 
    "INSERT INTO `tbl_timesheet`(`nik`, `id_annual`, `tgl`, `shift`, `project_desc`, `loc`) VALUES ('$nik', '$id_annual_leave', 'f' '$shift', '$project', '$cluster')"
);
```

column count doesn't match value:

[image]

Comment: Probably a typo : `'f' '$shift'` should be `'f', '$shift'`.

Comment: You didn't ask any question. This post is unclear.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not use this code. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'f' '$shift'` should be edited look like this

```
'$f', '$shift'
```